# Why does SqlConnection.Open performs slow sometimes

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, ado.net, connection-pooling

We have an app, which interacts with a number of MS SQL Servers via ADO.NET.
Current sql server setup: 5 instances with 3 databases on each instance. So, the total number of databases is 15.
The app performs operations (SELECT, UDPATE, INSERT) on each database (~2000 operations per second total).
We call `SqlConnection.Open()` before and `SqlConnection.Close()` after each operation, using standard ado.net connection pooling feature.
It goes well, but sometimes (~1% of total count of calls) `SqlConnection.Open()` takes from 1 to 3 seconds. And this hurts our perfomance, it is vital for us.

Connection string example:

```
<add name="cs1" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase1;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=100;Min Pool size=16;App=BM_OFF_B"/>
```

According to performance counters, the number of pooled connection keeps stable, meaning new connections are not created, only existing are reused.

The question is: why does `SqlConnection.Open()` takes up to 3 seconds while physical connections aren't created? How to solve this perfomance problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you're disposing of your connection objects? And have you verified that this is not just one of the database servers that has a high load at that time?

Comment: Yes, we dispose connections each time we close it. The distribution of operations between servers and databases is normal.

Comment: Sure sounds like a physical connection being opened.  Even if the number remains stable, are they getting closed and re-opened occasionally?

Comment: Which connection pooler class are you using? Do you have enough licenses when connecting to the server? Are your clients connecting directly to the server or are you using a middle-tier?

Comment: Check the reclaimed connection Performance counter to see if there are connections you are forgetting to explicit dispose.